# Proving a formula for the recursive series $w_n=-[w_1+w_2+\cdots +w_{n-1}]+\sqrt{[w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_{n-1}]^2+w_1^2}$ holds for all $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

I have a recursive series within problem I am trying to solve. I need to create a non-recursive formula in terms of $w_1$ and $n$ and prove it works for $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. I have found a pattern, but am unsure on how to prove it.

$$w_1 = x$$
$$w_2 = -w_1 + \sqrt{w_1^2 + w_1^2}$$
$$w_3 = -[w_1 + w_2] + \sqrt{[w_1+w_2]^2+w_1^2}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$w_n = -[w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_{n-1}] + \sqrt{[w_1+w_2+\cdots + w_{n-1}]^2+w_1^2}$$

Through substitution and simplification, I found a pattern. All terms cancelled out except $w_1$, and seemed to follow a pattern. So, I created a formula.
$$w_1 = r$$
$$w_2 = r(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1})$$
$$w_3 = r(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})$$
$$\vdots$$
$$w_n = r(\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1})$$

I have substituted up to $n=7$, and the formula holds. I would like to prove this formula works for all $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$. However, I don't know how to manipulate the equation when it is in series form, since my substitution method requires the solution to all previous terms in the series (hence, recursion).

EDIT 1:
Following Abel Wong's comment, I have tried (and got stuck) making a proof through induction. I'll walk through my proof so far.

I'm trying to prove the following equivalence.
$$-[w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_{n-1}] + \sqrt{[w_1+w_2+\cdots + w_{n-1}]^2+w_1^2}=w_1(\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1})$$

-- start proof --

Firstly, we validate the base cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.

$n=1$
$$-[0]+\sqrt{w_1^2}=w_1(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{1-1})$$
$$w_1=w_1$$

$n=2$
$$-[w_1]+\sqrt{[w_1]^2+w_1^2}=w_1(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2-1})$$
$$-[w_1]+\sqrt{2w_1^2}=w_1(\sqrt{2}-1)$$
$$\sqrt{2}w_1-[w_1]=w_1(\sqrt{2}-1)$$
$$w_1(\sqrt{2}-1)=w_1(\sqrt{2}-1)$$

Secondly, we assume our equality holds for $n=k$ (M.I.A).
$$-[w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_{k-1}] + \sqrt{[k_1+k_2+\cdots + k_{n-1}]^2+k_1^2}=k_1(\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1})$$

Thirdly, we show that our equality holds for $n=k+1$ (M.I).
We convert the finite series into sigma notation.

$$- \sum^{k}_{i=1} w_i + \sqrt{ (\sum^{k}_{i=1} \sum^{k}_{j=i} w_i w_j) + w_1^2} \  =? \ w_1(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})$$

-- end (incomplete) proof --

From my understanding, we must manipulate the LHS to match the RHS. Ideally, we can use the M.I.A to substitute in to simplify. However, because $w_n$ is recursive and in a series, I have no idea how to manipulate the equation.

Can someone help?
--  Sour_Tooth

Comment: Use M.I. Call the statement P(n). Then: P(1) is true. Assume P(n) is true for n=1,...,k. Then proof P(n+1) is true.

Comment: @AbelWong I have tried using induction, but could not get very far. I do not know how to manipulate the infinite series to prove the equivalency at $n=k+1$. I've edited my post to demonstrate my attempt. May you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$w_n = -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k + \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k)^2+r^2}
$
and
$w_k
=r(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})$
for $k=1..n-1
$
then
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})
=r\sqrt{n-1}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
w_n 
&= -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k + \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k)^2+r^2}\\
&= -r\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{(r\sqrt{n-1})^2+r^2}\\
&= -r\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{nr^2}\\
&= -r\sqrt{n-1} + r\sqrt{n}\\
&= r(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: How does the jump to $r(\sqrt{n-1})$ happen?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}w_k
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})
=r\sqrt{n-1}$

Comment: How do we show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} r(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}) = r\sqrt{n-1}$?

Comment: I believe [this calculation](https://www.emathhelp.net/?f=r%28%5Csqrt%7Bk%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bk-1%7D%29&var=k&a=1&b=n-1&action=series+and+sum) simplifies the "telescoping series." I understand now. Thanks again!